# Is there a smarter alternative to Trang for generating XSD from xml files

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to generate an XSD from multiple xml example files and have been using trang.

Unfortunately it is not that smart and gives lots of methods like getThingOrOtherThing(), treats all elements with the same name as the same and has no means to configure. 
Ideally I'd like something that you can configure ( a bit like xjc binding file ).

Thanks, Tom

Comment: How much are you willing to spend?

Comment: Oxygen/XML generates pretty decent XSDs from XML samples, but it's a commercial product in the $100-$1000 range (order of magnitude).

Comment: @Jim Garrison - I believe that Oxygen use trang to do that.

Answer (score 0):

NOTICE this `trang` issue is solved since 2012.